# The level of learning difficulty of English as a second language for non-native speakers

Tags: discussion

For French native speakers, English as a second language must be relatively EASIER to learn compared to the effort needed by Japanese native speakers.

**I wonder whether there is a study to rank the effort level needed for non-English native speakers to learn English as a second language?**

For example, in a 10-point ranking, maybe for French speakers the effort level is 3 while for Japanese speakers the effort level is 8?

It would be nice to also know the reasons why learning English as a second language is hard for native speakers of non-English languages.

I hope this question is acceptable at least on the meta site, if not for the main site.  Otherwise, please let me know how to update this question for this site, or whether another site is more appropriate.

Comment: I've seen a similar list that shows the relative difficulty of learning another language for English speakers, and I imagine the inverse holds too. I haven't seen it for 20-ish years. This Meta site is for questions about the ELL site itself, so your question is certainly off-topic here. However, it seems it might be a good fit at [Language Learning SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Consider asking there

Comment: In practice, I suspect some of this has to do with factors outside the language. For example, how much learning material and resources are available in the native language? How much contact is available with English, either through people or media?

Comment: As a Language Learning SE moderator, I agree with @gotube that this topic is better suited to that site than on a meta site. However, the question may need a bit more focus (ranking or reasons).

Comment: @gotube I think this is the one you're talking about? https://effectivelanguagelearning.com/language-guide/language-difficulty/

Comment: @Eden0516 That's the one. Tx!